# Migration Large Java App from MyBatis to ORM

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, mybatis

this question is more of a broad idea to replace the myBatis with Hibernate ORM.

I tried to google but couldn't find any solution for this.

So currently we are using MyBatis with the following structure:

```
    some-module
    some-module
    some-module
        domain.model
            SomeDBO 
            SomeDBO
        domain.repository
            some-mapper.xml // <--- this contains resultMap & sql queries
            some-mapper.xml // <--- this contains resultMap & sql queries
    some-module
        src.main.java.resources
            mybatis.xml // <--- This contains referece for typeAliases & mappers
```

Now the problem is mostly we don't have to write the complex queries to get or insert data.
But as our application is growing maintaining SQL queries is becoming a pain in the ass.

So we are thinking to somehow move from MyBatis to [Hibernate ORM](https://hibernate.org/orm/) to reduce maintain/creating the SQL.

I know MyBatis also supported the generator but I'm not looking into that option.

The possible solution which I'm thinking is to somehow maintain the backward compatibility with MyBatis and write new features with Hibernate ORM and gradually remove the MyBatis from the codebase.

Answer (score 0):

migrate to Hibernate ORM is really hard for mybatis, you can use mybatis and hibernate together. Or you can try a Intellij plugin https://gejun123456.github.io/MyBatisCodeHelper-Pro/#/en/typeSafe to improve your productivity with mybatis.

Comment: do you have any example which shows like we can use MyBatis with Hibernate ORM

Comment: the plugin idea which you shared if more of an auto-completion to write SQL queries. Which I don't want

Comment: not only auto completion but check if your sql is right. refactor code. inspection and can generate code like springdatajpa. There is a project https://github.com/liumangafei/spring-boot-jpa-mybatis-gradle that use mybatis and hiberate together, you can check it.

Comment: Mybatis can be used with Hibernate ORM. But do take note that not to use Mybatis to work on the POJO which is currently held by Hibernate session in the same transaction.